# Auto generate invoices at particular intervals of time - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model

In my Rails application, I have a table where I keep my client invoices , and I want the system to auto generate an invoice to all clients once in every month automatically. Table `clients` and table `invoice` are associated to each other.

## client

```
has_many :invoices
```

## invoices

```
belongs_to :client
```

does anyone have any idea about how to do this automatically ?

The data must be generated on the first day of every month and must be kept in the invoices tables
So, as you'ved guessed i'm really new to RoR , i'ved written a method in the invoices model to use in cron , can anyone look over it and tell if i'm on the correct path(i'm already using the app and don't want to mess the database), the value of the invoice (suma) is kept in clientpf.suma  and my invoice model is named Factpf here is my method

## Facpf method for Cron

```
def self.generare

@clientpfs = Clientpf.all
@clientpfs.each do |clientpf|
self.suma  = clientpf.ab
self.clientpf_id = clientpf.id
Factpf.create!
end
end
```

Comment: So, as you'ved guessed i'm really new to RoR , i'ved written a method in the invoices model to use in cron , can anyone look over it and tell if i'm on the correct path(i'm already using the app and don't want to mess the database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem and do as follows:

Example `schedule.rb` file,

```
every '0 0 1 * *' do
  runner "Model.your_method_generating_invoice"
end
```

The notation '0 0 1 * *' indicates that it will run once in every month.

To know more about the notation '0 0 1 * *', just refer [here](http://www.manpagez.com/man/5/crontab/)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you very much Rajesh , for the answer and for editing my question.

Comment: Hope you can accept the answer if it really helped you.

Comment: Yes it's a great answer , and from what i read about Cron so far i think it's the perfect solution